# Is it possible to have a connected manifold that is a double cover of a 2-sphere?

Tags: geometry, manifolds, covering-spaces, spheres

I have come up with a branched covering, but it necessarily has two branch points. From that I'm assuming that it can't be done, possibly related to the hairy ball theorem, but I don't know how to prove it either way.

The branched covering is two spheres which both have a great circle segment between two branch points along which they are connected. So if you're traveling on the first sphere and cross that segment, you are now traveling on the second sphere and vice-versa. Of course, at the branch points there is a discontinuity.

Is there a simple way to demonstrate that there is no such manifold? Or is there some construction which avoids the branch points?

I apologize for any misuse of terminology. Corrections welcome.

Comment: "Branched covering" is the correct term, but "poles" should be probably be replaced by "branch points". The standard mathematical definition of a pole in a map between surfaces is different than the one you are using.

Comment: This is really part of the content in the first part of a standard first course on algebraic topology. A possible source for that material is the first chapter of Hatcher. All one needs to know is that $S^2$ is simply-connected and that there is a unique connected simply-connected cover of any (nice enough) space up to homeomorphism. Both of these are standard facts proven in such a course.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I will go over that material and see if I can get the hang of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the sphere $S^{2}$ is simply-connected, it admits no connected, non-trivial covering. (If it matters, the trouble isn't related to the hairy ball theorem: The $3$-sphere admits continuous, nowhere-vanishing vector fields, but admits no connected, non-trivial covering, again because $S^{3}$ is simply-connected.)

Comment: I'm glad to hear there's a definitive answer, thank you. What do I need to know to understand why that answer is correct? For example, how would I demonstrate it to someone else?

Comment: Suppose $Y$ is simply connected and $p : X \to Y$ is a covering, with $X$ (path) connected. If $p^{-1}(y)$ has two distinct points, say $x, x' \in p^{-1}(y)$, then choose a path $\gamma$ joining $x$ to $x'$. Then the path $p \circ \gamma$ is a loop around $y$ which cannot be nullhomotopic (essentially because a nullhomotopy would lift to a nullhomotopy of $\gamma$, but that's impossible because the endpoints of $\gamma$ are distinct).

Comment: Since we assumed $Y$ is simply connected, this must mean that $X$ is a $1$-fold covering, and therefore $p$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: You can also appeal to the more general correspondence between isomorphism classes of covering spaces of $Y$ and subgroups of $\pi_1(Y)$; just search topology books for "classification of covering spaces" (it's definitely in Hatcher for example).